# WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER vs WP_DEBUG ? What to use and when to use to see errors?

Tags: errors

After introduction of `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` I'm confused with existing `WP_DEBUG` feature.
Now what's the difference here?

I mean what constant I should use to see the error if I use `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` then what's the meaning of `WP_DEBUG` now?

Even though I went through some of tickets on WordPress but I can't figure out the use of `WP_DEBUG` now.

Did WordPress ends the use of `WP_DEBUG` ?
After introduction of new constant `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` I'm not able to see errors anymore with `define("WP_DEBUG",true)`.
I know about `display_errors` setting in php.ini so not expecting this solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those constants do different things.

- The `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` constant is for disabling the [new fatal error recovery feature](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/04/16/fatal-error-recovery-mode-in-5-2/) introduced in WordPress 5.2. This new feature ensures that fatal errors from plugins don't lock you out of your site, and that front-end users get some kind of "technical difficulties" message, rather than a white screen.
- The `WP_DEBUG` constant is to enable a debug mode that displays all PHP error messages and warnings on the front-end, as well as WordPress specific messages such as deprecation notices.

So you can see that they are not really related. The fatal error recovery functionality is intended to be used in production, so that white screens and PHP error messages are not displayed to users. While debug mode is intended to be used in a development environment to debug issues when developing a theme or plugin.

In a production environment (so a live site), neither constant should be enabled. Fatal error recovery should be enabled, and debug mode should be disabled.

In a development environment, you probably don't need fatal error recovery, and you'll likely want debug mode to be enabled.

If for some reason you need to debug issues on a live site, then debug mode might need to be enabled, but in that case you should have `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` set to `false`, and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` set to `true`, so that you can debug error messages from a log file, rather than exposing them to users.

So in a **development environment** you probably want:

```
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

And in a **production environment** you probably want (these would be the same as not manually defining them):

```
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

And if you need to **debug a live site** you could use:

```
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My doubt is cleared now:)

Answer (score 1):

Very detailed answer by Jacob Peattie and I would +1 that for sure. I'd also like to add that you can use the following ini_set commands and also specify your debug log location.

```
@ini_set('log_errors','On'); // This is essentialy what ('WP_DEBUG', true) does.
@ini_set('display_errors','Off'); // Avoid the ugly display of errors on live sites.
@ini_set('error_log','/home/domain.com/logs/php_error.log'); // Set your log path.
```